# How to remove everything outside of vertical bars in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

For example:

"Duden | wandeln | Rechtschreibung, Bedeutung, Definition | entsenden | Rechtschreibung, Bedeutung (...)"

to:

"wandeln 
entsenden"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Rechtschreibung, Bedeutung, Definition* is also between vertical bars. What's the rule for excluding it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using notepad++ regex

```
Find: ([^\|]+)?\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)
Replace: $2
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?\|\h*(.+?)\h*\|.+?\|\h*(.+?)\h*\|.*$`
- Replace with: `$1 $2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+?       # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \|        # 1 pipe character
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  (.+?)     # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \|        # 1 pipe character
  .+?       # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \|        # 1 pipe character
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  (.+?)     # group 2, 1 or more any character, not greedy
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \|        # 1 pipe character
  .*        # 0 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
            : 1 space
$2          : content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
wandeln entsenden
```